# Bootstrap grid panels rows whitespace

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have website with Bootstrap, and I'm dynamicly loading content with PHP into panels, enclosed in divs `col-md-6`.

After two entries the script will close the row and start a new one (`<div class="row">`).

When one panel is taller then another in the row there is ugly whitespace under the smaller panel. How can I get rid of this whitespace, and make panels stack under each other in two rows?

UPDATE: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rwp3gcm/)
I tried lot of things from provided link, nothing works. Here is version with jQuery script (my preferred solution)

Comment: Could you show a snippet of code? Or make a jsfiddle?

Comment: How can anyone troubleshoot your code if you do not provide any code to troubleshoot?

Comment: I think you need to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: The panels won’t sit snug vertically if you’re putting them in rows of two, as the rows clear themselves. If you want a snug grid, look at a JavaScript plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Or think in columns before rows, instead of rows before columns.

Comment: @MikeViscontini I just added code

Comment: @SeanStopnik I just added code